# Test Failure : java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, testing

I have a project that runs correctly in the IDE, but when I tried bundle it into a "jar" file using the "mvn" command it fails due to "Test Failure": **java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext.**

Here is the test class (the default one):

```
package com.example.businesslogicserver;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;

@SpringBootTest
class BusinessLogicServerApplicationTests {

    @Test
    void contextLoads() {
    }

}
```

the application class

```
package com.example.businesslogicserver;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

@SpringBootApplication
public class BusinessLogicServerApplication {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(BusinessLogicServerApplication.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SpringApplication.run(BusinessLogicServerApplication.class, args);
        logger.info("Your Spring Boot Application has started successfully...");
    }
}
```

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.1</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>business-logic-server</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>business-logic-server</name>
    <description>Project for Handling a list of items</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-api</artifactId>
            <version>0.11.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-impl</artifactId>
            <version>0.11.2</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>0.11.2</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>

        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**application.properties**

```
server.port=9090
auth.server.base.url=http://localhost:8080
jwt.signing.key=very1secure2secret3key_10264564684846d4fdfhdfsasa1235saa23154asas

spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/itemlist?serverTimezone=UTC
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.data.rest.basePath=/api
```

Can anyone help please ? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

you are having this error because it's now recommended to specify the class (classes) you would like to test :
[image]

To fix , you just have to specify the classes like this :

[image]

Or if you want to ignore the tests , you can simply run :

**mvn clean install -Dmaven.test.skip=true**

Comment: @Tony is there any other solution to the problem cause I have the classes added in the SpringbootTest

Comment: disabling test is not a solution, it is hiding the problem.  The fact that spring context cannot be loaded suggest more serious issue with the application.  Unfortunatelly, I dont know solution, I am also trying to figure out why one of my inherited apps has this problem.  Also, specifying a class in `@SpringBootTest` on application class makes no sense since you need the app context to run integration tests and in this case it is the main app class.  This answer should not be accepted as it is plain wrong

Answer (score 2):

Got the same error for the same reason although in a different context, with Gradle, while building a plain Spring Boot 3.1.2 generated by [Spring Initializr](https://start.spring.io):

```
> Task :server:test FAILED

ServerTests > contextLoads() FAILED
    java.lang.IllegalStateException at DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:143
        Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException at Assert.java:713
```

Tried the approaches above without success.
Solved it by separating the classes containing tests from the one loading the Spring Boot context for running those tests, like so:

**src/main/java/Server.java**

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Server {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Server.class, args);
    }
}
```

**src/test/java/ServerTests.java**

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

class ServerTests {
    @Test
    void contextLoads() {
    }
}
```

**src/test/java/TestSuite.java**

```
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;

@SpringBootTest(classes = {ServerTests.class})
class TestSuite {
}
```

**Output**

```
./gradlew clean build

> Task :server:test
ServerTests > contextLoads() PASSED
BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 3s
```

**Environment**

- JDK 17
- Gradle 8.2.1
- Spring Boot 3.1.2

Answer (score 1):

Adding the main class in the annotation `@SpringBootTest()` worked for me, as Tony said in the comment above.