# My Spring Boot test says "IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext for such and such"

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing

I am new to testing in Spring Boot with two years of testing experience in JS and Jest. The particulars of configuring the spring boot tests are giving me trouble.

My goal is to run integration tests for Spring Boot. On the path to running those tests, I need to run smaller unit tests. I am blocked by the same bug in all three test files.

My expected result is that my tests run and show errors that are caused by the inputs of the tests, or from the code that the tests are testing.

My actual result is that the tests don't even get to run because of an error message.

Here is my error message output, the part that looked relevant to me:

```
StorageApplicationTests STANDARD_OUT
    2024-01-05T12:07:52.882-08:00  WARN 340608 --- [    Test worker] o.s.test.context.TestContextManager      : Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener] to prepare test instance [com.pluto.storage.StorageApplicationTests@675ec28b]

    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext for [WebMergedContextConfiguration@66a82a13 testClass = com.pluto.storage.StorageApplicationTests, locations = [], classes = [com.pluto.storage.StorageApplication], contextInitializerClasses = [], activeProfiles = [], propertySourceDescriptors = [], propertySourceProperties = ["org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper=true"], contextCustomizers = [org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.actuate.observability.ObservabilityContextCustomizerFactory$DisableObservabilityContextCustomizer@1f, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizer@77d67cf3, org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@126945f9, org.springframework.boot.test.json.DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizerFactory$DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizer@b1712f3, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.web.client.TestRestTemplateContextCustomizer@6bbe2511, org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestAnnotation@bd4c82a5], resourceBasePath = "src/main/webapp", contextLoader = org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader, parent = null]
```

Here is my code in `storage/src/test/java/com/pluto/storage/StorageApplicationTests.java`:

```
package com.pluto.storage;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertNotNull;

import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

//import com.pluto.storage.StorageApplication;
//import com.pluto.storage.controllers.*;

@SpringBootTest()
class StorageApplicationTests {
    @Test
    void contextLoads() {
        assertNotNull("foo");
    }
}
```

Here is a tutorial that suggests I am doing it right, or rather that the issue stems from somewhere I am not looking at: https://spring.io/guides/gs/testing-web/

If I were to label any part of the error message as suspicious, it would be the part that says `resourceBasePath = "src/main/webapp"`. I have no such path in my project. The folders under `/src/main` are the java and resources folders. But I googled "spring boot change resourceBasePath" and saw no hits for that command.

I also tried adding `@AutoConfigureMockMvc` but I think this is too far upstream for that to be relevant.

I read a bunch of stackoverflow posts about "IllegalStateException Failed to load ApplicationContext." none helped. examples:

1. [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61898647/spring-boot-junit-test-applicationcontext-failed-to-load) talks about "@AutoConfigureMockMvc was causing the issue with the way it was auto-configuring MockMvc from my integration tests. Used @ContextConfiguration instead and manually setup MockMvc using WebApplicationContext." That doesn't apply to me because I'm not using that tag, and nor do I have a MockMvc in my program.
2. [Test Failure : java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65903358/test-failure-java-lang-illegalstateexception-failed-to-load-applicationcontex) talks about "Adding the main class in the annotation @SpringBootTest()". Example implementation:

```
import com.pluto.storage.StorageApplication;

@SpringBootTest(classes = StorageApplication.class)
class StorageApplicationTests {
    @Test
    void contextLoads() {
        assertNotNull("foo");
    }
}
```

Same error.

3. [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44764218/junit-error-failed-to-load-applicationcontext) [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5058294/java-project-failed-to-load-applicationcontext)  talk about `the "app.properties" and " applicationContext" were not being copied into the testing resources` and  `put the applicationContext.xml file in the src/main/resources directory`. But my application.properties file only contains database connection info, and there is no `applicationContext.xml` in my program.

I saw that errors can be caused by other errors "further down" the full stack trace. So here it is, with some truncation to make it fit the word count:

```
StorageApplicationTests > contextLoads() FAILED
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext for [WebMergedContextConfiguration@61359e87 testClass = com.pluto.storage.StorageApplicationTests, locations = [], classes = [com.pluto.storage.StorageApplication], contextInitializerClasses = [], activeProfiles = [], propertySourceDescriptors = [], propertySourceProperties = ["org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper=true"], contextCustomizers = [org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.actuate.observability.ObservabilityContextCustomizerFactory$DisableObservabilityContextCustomizer@1f, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizer@42039326, org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@63787180, org.springframework.boot.test.json.DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizerFactory$DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizer@386f0da3, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.web.client.TestRestTemplateContextCustomizer@2ea6e30c, org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestAnnotation@842f4968], resourceBasePath = "src/main/webapp", contextLoader = org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader, parent = null]
// ...
        Caused by:
        org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'routerFunctionMapping' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.function.support.RouterFunctionMapping]: Factory method 'routerFunctionMapping' threw exception with message: Error creating bean with name 'messageConverters' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/http/HttpMessageConvertersAutoConfiguration.class]: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.http.HttpMessageConverters]: Factory method 'messageConverters' threw exception with message: Error creating bean with name 'mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/http/JacksonHttpMessageConvertersConfiguration$MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverterConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'jacksonObjectMapper' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jackson/JacksonAutoConfiguration$JacksonObjectMapperConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'jacksonObjectMapper' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'jacksonObjectMapperBuilder' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jackson/JacksonAutoConfiguration$JacksonObjectMapperBuilderConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'jacksonObjectMapperBuilder' parameter 1: Error creating bean with name 'standardJacksonObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jackson/JacksonAutoConfiguration$Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizerConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'standardJacksonObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'spring.jackson-org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson.JacksonProperties': Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson.JacksonProperties]: Constructor threw exception
// ...app//org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:152)
            ... 86 more

            Caused by:
            org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.function.support.RouterFunctionMapping]: Factory method 'routerFunctionMapping' threw exception with message: Error creating bean with name 'messageConverters' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/http/HttpMessageConvertersAutoConfiguration.class]: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.http.HttpMessageConverters]: Factory method 'messageConverters' threw exception with message: Error creating bean with name 'mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/http/JacksonHttpMessageConvertersConfiguration$MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverterConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'jacksonObjectMapper' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jackson/JacksonAutoConfiguration$JacksonObjectMapperConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'jacksonObjectMapper' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'jacksonObjectMapperBuilder' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jackson/JacksonAutoConfiguration$JacksonObjectMapperBuilderConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'jacksonObjectMapperBuilder' parameter 1: Error creating bean with name 'standardJacksonObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jackson/JacksonAutoConfiguration$Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizerConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'standardJacksonObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'spring.jackson-org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson.JacksonProperties': Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson.JacksonProperties]: Constructor threw exception
                at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:177)
                at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:651)
                ... 110 more

                Caused by:
                org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'messageConverters' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/http/HttpMessageConvertersAutoConfiguration.class]: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.http.HttpMessageConverters]: Factory method 'messageConverters' threw exception with message: Error creating bean with name 'mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/http/JacksonHttpMessageConvertersConfiguration$MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverterConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'jacksonObjectMapper' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jackson/JacksonAutoConfiguration$JacksonObjectMapperConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'jacksonObjectMapper' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'jacksonObjectMapperBuilder' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jackson/JacksonAutoConfiguration$JacksonObjectMapperBuilderConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'jacksonObjectMapperBuilder' parameter 1: Error creating bean with name 'standardJacksonObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jackson/JacksonAutoConfiguration$Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizerConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'standardJacksonObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'spring.jackson-org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson.JacksonProperties': Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson.JacksonProperties]: Constructor threw exception
// ...app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:140)
                    ... 111 more

                    Caused by:
                    org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.http.HttpMessageConverters]: Factory method 'messageConverters' threw exception with message: Error creating bean with name 'mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/http/JacksonHttpMessageConvertersConfiguration$MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverterConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'jacksonObjectMapper' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jackson/JacksonAutoConfiguration$JacksonObjectMapperConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'jacksonObjectMapper' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'jacksonObjectMapperBuilder' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jackson/JacksonAutoConfiguration$JacksonObjectMapperBuilderConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'jacksonObjectMapperBuilder' parameter 1: Error creating bean with name 'standardJacksonObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jackson/JacksonAutoConfiguration$Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizerConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'standardJacksonObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'spring.jackson-org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson.JacksonProperties': Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson.JacksonProperties]: Constructor threw exception
                        at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:177)
                        at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:651)
                        ... 134 more

                        Caused by:
                        org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/http/JacksonHttpMessageConvertersConfiguration$MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverterConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'jacksonObjectMapper' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jackson/JacksonAutoConfiguration$JacksonObjectMapperConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'jacksonObjectMapper' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'jacksonObjectMapperBuilder' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jackson/JacksonAutoConfiguration$JacksonObjectMapperBuilderConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'jacksonObjectMapperBuilder' parameter 1: Error creating bean with name 'standardJacksonObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jackson/JacksonAutoConfiguration$Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizerConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'standardJacksonObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'spring.jackson-org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson.JacksonProperties': Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson.JacksonProperties]: Constructor threw exception
// ...
                            at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:140)
                            ... 135 more

                            Caused by:
                            org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'jacksonObjectMapper' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jackson/JacksonAutoConfiguration$JacksonObjectMapperConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'jacksonObjectMapper' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'jacksonObjectMapperBuilder' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jackson/JacksonAutoConfiguration$JacksonObjectMapperBuilderConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'jacksonObjectMapperBuilder' parameter 1: Error creating bean with name 'standardJacksonObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jackson/JacksonAutoConfiguration$Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizerConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'standardJacksonObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'spring.jackson-org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson.JacksonProperties': Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson.JacksonProperties]: Constructor threw exception
// ...
                                at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:789)
                                ... 157 more

                                Caused by:
                                org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'jacksonObjectMapperBuilder' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jackson/JacksonAutoConfiguration$JacksonObjectMapperBuilderConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'jacksonObjectMapperBuilder' parameter 1: Error creating bean with name 'standardJacksonObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jackson/JacksonAutoConfiguration$Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizerConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'standardJacksonObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'spring.jackson-org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson.JacksonProperties': Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson.JacksonProperties]: Constructor threw exception
// ...app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:911)
                                    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:789)
                                    ... 171 more

                                    Caused by:
                                    org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'standardJacksonObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jackson/JacksonAutoConfiguration$Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizerConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'standardJacksonObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'spring.jackson-org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson.JacksonProperties': Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson.JacksonProperties]: Constructor threw exception
                                        at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:802)
                                        at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:546)
// ...
                                        at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:789)
                                        ... 183 more

                                        Caused by:
                                        org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'spring.jackson-org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson.JacksonProperties': Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson.JacksonProperties]: Constructor threw exception
                                            at // ...
                                            at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:789)
                                            ... 201 more

                                            Caused by:
                                            org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson.JacksonProperties]: Constructor threw exception
                                                at app//org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:223)
                                                at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:88)
                                                at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1310)
                                                ... 213 more

                                                Caused by:
                                                java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/cfg/EnumFeature
                                                    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson.JacksonProperties$Datatype.<init>(JacksonProperties.java:236)

// ...

org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:197)
                                                    ... 215 more

                                                    Caused by:
                                                    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.cfg.EnumFeature
                                                        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
                                                        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
                                                        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:525)
                                                        ... 223 more
```

I do have Jackson in my Gradle dependencies: `testImplementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.12.5'` and it isn't used in this test.

I am out of ideas! Help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the exception stacktrace says Spring is unable to create one of the beans due to ClassNotFoundException:
`java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.cfg.EnumFeature`

In jackson documentation we can see than com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.cfg.EnumFeature exists since 2.14 version, while you have 2.12 version (https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.14/index.html?com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/cfg/EnumFeature.html).

I think that if you switch to a newer version of jackson it will fix the problem. Try
`implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.16.1'`

Comment: Glorious. Thank you. The change worked and now I can see `/storage/build/reports/tests/test/classes/com.pluto.storage.StorageApplicationTests.html` has a report that says "100% successful"